# synthesizeToFile returns -1 and i am not able to create file using Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()

Tags: android

I am trying to convert string into .wav file, to use pause/resume functionality into texttospeech, but i cannot create the file.

```
    public void fileCreate() {
    String inputText = editText.getText().toString();

    HashMap<String, String> myHashRender = new HashMap<String, String>();
    myHashRender.put(TextToSpeech.Engine.KEY_PARAM_UTTERANCE_ID, inputText);
    Log.d("TAG", "successfully created hashmap");

    int sr = textToSpeech.synthesizeToFile(inputText, myHashRender,      Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+File.separator+"tts_file.wav");
    Log.d("TAG", "synthesize returns = " + sr);
    File fileTTS = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            .getAbsolutePath(),"tts_file.wav");

    if (fileTTS.exists()) {
        Log.d("TAG", "successfully created fileTTS");
    }
    else {
        Log.d("TAG", "failed while creating fileTTS");
    }

    fileUri = Uri.fromFile(fileTTS);
    Log.d("TAG", "successfully created uri link: " + fileUri.getPath());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've seen that you're using the deprecated method that receives 3 parameters. Have you already tried to used synthesizeToFile (CharSequence text, Bundle params, File file,  String utteranceId)?

Also, did you add the permission in your manifest?

```
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

You should also check if file exists in either listeners onUtteranceCompletedListener or UtteranceProgressListener, because the method synthesizeToFile is asynchronous.

Comment: yes i have given permission in manifest file above the application tag, but in logcat monitor it shows java.io.FileNotFoundException: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied) @cristianorbs

Comment: did you find any answer??